# Значение слова "конфронтировать"

Tags: значение-слов

Лично я воспринимаю слово "конфронтировать" как "противостоять", "сопротивляться", но столкнулся с видео, где оно используется в значении "принимать", "соглашаться" (контекст не политический).

Стал гуглить и обнаружил, что слово довольно редкое и есть такие определения:

https://gallicismes.academic.ru/20325/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

> 1. устар. Сравнивать, сличать тексты. Сопоставлять, сравнивать. Михельсон 1883. Мы ниже подписавшиеся свидетельствуем, что настоящую копию духовной кн. Антиоха Дмитриевича сносили и конфронтировали c оригинальною. 1744. Кантемир 1868 2 356.
> 2. полит. Противопоставляться, вести конфронтацию. Не будем "конфронтировать" (название статьи). // Скляревская 1998. Един. Конфронтист а, м. - Новоявленных "центристов" можно отнести к заурядным "конфронтистам", приспособившимся к существующему компрадорскому режиму. МГ 1995 9 250.

http://www.slovochel.ru/konfrontirovat.htm

> 1. Быть лицом к лицу, не избегая и не уклоняясь.
> 2. Способность находиться лицом к чему-то без попыток избежать и уклониться, присутствовать комфортно и воспринимать, особенно в случае вызова, неприязни или обвинения.
>
> Пояснения:
>
> Способность Конфронтировать - это, в действительности, способность присутствовать комфортно и воспринимать.
>
> Мир никогда не будет ярким для тех, кто не может Конфронтировать с ним.
> Если кто-то говорит Вам –”там всё плохо”, то весь фокус состоит в том, что он пытается удержать Вас от Конфронтирования с чем-нибудь, и, таким образом, отдалить Вас от жизни.
>
> Нервные подёргивания, напряжения основываются на нежелании Конфронтировать. Когда это желание восстановлено, эти недостатки имеют тенденцию к исчезновению.

Аналогичные значения описываются тут (хотя, это на словарь не претендует):
https://magic-unlimited.livejournal.com/20164.html

> "КОНФРОНТ (CONFRONT): (глаг. конфронтировать)
>
> 1. Действие по бытию, при котором имеется способность находиться лицом к чему-то. [..]
> 2. Способность присутствовать комфортно и воспринимать. [..]
> 3. Конфронт, сам по себе, является результатом и конечным продуктом. Он сам по себе не является каким-то действием, он является способностью. [..]
> 4. (глагол) Быть лицом к чему-то, без попыток избежать и уклониться. [..]
> 5. Стоять лицом к кому-то или напротив, особенно в случае вызова, неприязни или обвинения. [..]
> 6. Быть способным видеть, что есть, или чего нет перед человеком. [..]
> 7. Прямое наблюдение. [..]
>
> НЕКОНФРОНТ (NON CONFRONT): сокр. “неспособность конфронтировать”. Неспособность встать лицом к лицу, не уступая и не уклоняясь. Способность конфронтировать - это способность присутствовать, не испытывая неудобств, и воспринимать".

**Насколько корректно использовать глагол "конфронтировать" и сочетание "способность конфронтировать" в значениях принятия, согласия и комфорта?**

Answer (score 1):

Front - это дословно "надбровная дуга" или передняя часть чего-то.

Где ж фраза-то? Confrontation - "action of bringing two parties face to face". То бишь, с глазу на глаз.

Конфронтир - "to stand in front of, be facing," from French confronter (15c.). Встречать врага грудью.

"способность конфронтировать" - лучше переводить на собственно инглиш - [ability to confront](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/ability+to+confront).

Либо это всякая психологическая установочная хрень вроде:

> Встречайте жизненные трудности лицом к лицу.
>
> Впрочем, ее «пробуждение» - это даже не ответ, а скорее начало нового
> пути. Популярная психология учит встречать жизненные проблемы лицом к
> лицу и решать их. Героиня «Пробуждения» свои проблемы тоже пыталась
> решить, без конца анализируя себя.

**Принятие - встретить/столкнуться(лицом к лицу) и принять реальность**...

> 1. **Acceptance – Confront and accept the reality**, no matter how bleak or painful. This is the necessary first step for healing. 2. Affirmation -- Say ‘yes’ to life; believe that life is worth living in spite of the suffering and pain.

Comment: Ничего не понял... _"Либо это всякая психологическая установочная хрень"_ - да, контекст был типа того. Это действительно влияет на значение?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну как могу объясняю. Слово может confront может быть во фразе Acceptance – Confront and accept the reality - которую любят повторять в вариациях на всяких психотренингах, ну знаешь, американские гуру, вещают как жить надо и тп. Но видимо, при переводе, человек переводивший, не стал вникать в суть терминологии, потому пропало смысловое деление между Конфронт - столкнуться, встречать лицом со смысловым термином рядом - принятие. В итоге получилось что это одно и тоже. Конфронт - это вроде неотвратимость чего-то, ну а раз неотвратимо, это надо просто принять.

Comment: И в итоге получился корректный перевод, или так использовать нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно фразу целиком? Например, готовить можно еду, но готовка - это не обязательно еда и не равно еда, можно и гадость приготовить несъедобную, и тут также. Неотвратимость не обязательно принятие, хотя может к нему привести. Наверное, что-то не так, но нужен текст, чтобы ответить, что там не так.

Comment: Вот такая схема: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HK9.png. Источник - ютьюб, видео `5jMO5jAzgco` (вообще, я ему дислайк поставил), тайминг 2:58 - 4:02. Печатать его текст совершенно нет желания, автораспознавание там сработало посредственно.

Comment: Кажется, что то, что я цитирую во втором и третьем источнике, вполне сочетается с его использованием, поэтому, если что-то не так, то мне кажется, оно и в этих определениях должно быть не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://www.timecops.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2427 - Хаббард дианетика бла-бла . оригинал, можешь читать переводить) потом расскажи про что)

Comment: Procedure emphasis:

Communication (Mimicry, Learning)
Control (Absolute versions)

Commands:

All commands used in actual session are to be Havingness Scale commands, used with the above procedures.

The Havingness Scale is as follows:

Create
Contribute to
Confront
Have
Substitute
Waste
Substituted
Had
Confronted
Contributed to
Created

Comment: И что с этим делать?

Comment: картинка, что прислал, оттуда.